# Raspar parâmetros de um método post, com scrapy em python!

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Preciso coletar informações de um site, utilizando *spiders* dentro do ScraPy em Python, porém o site é um método *post* e estou aprendendo a linguagem enquanto desenvolvo o projeto. Achei um modelo de *post* porém não estou conseguindo rodá-lo de forma correta. O código que possuo é este:

```
scrapy.FormRequest(
    url='http://www.camex.gov.br/resolucoes-camex/resolucoes',
    formdata={
        'filter[search]': '',
        'filter[res]': '',
        'filter[ano]': '',
        'limit': paginas,
        'limitstart': quantidadeDeRegistros,
        'task': '',
        'boxchecked': 0,
        'filter_order': '',
        'filter_order_Dir': '',
        '46598c34d1ab5af3b00e8d84a4281fbc': 1,
        'list[fullordering]': 'null ASC'
    },
    callback=self.parsePagina
)
```

Está correto ou existe uma outra forma melhor de fazer?

Comment: Qual problema que você está enfrentando?

Comment: Como possuo pouca exp com python e estou usando a linguagem para desenvolver um projeto onde trabalho, não sei dizer se esse metodo está correto, pois não me retorna nada no log da IDE

Comment: Eu trabalho com scrapy, ele só irar retornar algo se você parsear o conteúdo no seu callback `parsePagina`, o que você tem nesse método?

Comment: possuo a seguinte função:     `def parsePagina(self, response):
        itemResolucao = response.xpath('//*[@id="resolucaoList"]/tbody/tr')
        urlBase = "http://www.camex.gov.br"
        for itens in itemResolucao:
            links_resolucoes = itens.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            if not '://' in links_resolucoes:
                link = urlBase + itens.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            req = Request(url=link, callback=self.parseResolucao)
            yield req
        print 'trabalhando na pagina'`

Comment: Pelo que entendi esse parsePagina, você pega cada link da listagem e depois realiza uma requisição pra cada resolução, então o parseamento do conteúdo é no parseResolucao?

Comment: isso, no parse resolução aplicamos uma classe própria do projeto, porem antes de tentar fazer o post ele capturava todas e somente informações relacioandas a primeira página do site

Comment: Ah certo, mas ainda não entendi qual sua dúvida, a sintaxe do seu código está correto.

Comment: O meu problema é que ele está indicando que o callback está incorreto, já pesquisei em várias fontes e não consigo identificar o problema existente.

Comment: Você pode postar o código completo desse seu spider? Assim eu posso olhar e lhe ajudar.

Comment: `class camax_mdic(Spider):
    name = "camax_mdic"
    start_urls = ["http://www.camex.gov.br/resolucoes-camex/resolucoes"]

    diretorio_temporario = settings["TEMP_DIR"]
    pdf2text = settings["PDF2TEXT"]
    data_dir = settings["DATA_DIR"]
    diretorio_arquivos = os.path.join(data_dir, name, "docs")
    link_arquivos = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugar-contents/normativas/src/camax_mdic/docs/'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': os.path.join(data_dir, 'camax_mdic', 'data', '%(time)s.json'),
    }`

Comment: ` def __init__(self):
        pathBase = settings['DATA_DIR']

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name)):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name))
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name, 'data')):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name, 'data'))
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name, 'docs')):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name, 'docs'))
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(pathBase, self.name, )
`

Comment: ` def parse(self, response):
        quantidadeDeRegistrosPorPagina = 20
        quantidadeDeRegistros = response.xpath('//*[@class="pagination-list"]/li/a[@title="Fim"]/@onclick').extract_first()[:-1].split('=')[1].replace(";","").replace("Joomla.submitform()return false","")
        quantidadeDePaginas = int(quantidadeDeRegistros)/quantidadeDeRegistrosPorPagina
        for paginas in xrange(0, quantidadeDePaginas, 1):`

Comment: Poste aqui: https://gist.github.com/ é melhor pra eu ver, nos comentarios fica dificil.

Comment: daí tem o post que   te mostrei

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jonathanigorpereira/d7c3e2277c0404a26eb349a618c11ccb

Comment: Vou testar aqui e já lhe retorno!

Answer (score 1):

Realizei alguns testes, esse problema acontece porque a página que você está tentando enviar o formulário possui dois elementos `form`. O scrapy está enviando a requisição pro primeiro, mas deveria ser o segundo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para corrigir isso e seu spider funcionar, você deve adicionar o atributo `formname` na chamada do método:

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    url='http://www.camex.gov.br/resolucoes-camex/resolucoes',
    formname="adminForm", # nome do form que você deseja enviar a request
    formdata={
            'filter[search]': '', #codigo omitido
```

Comment: este formname pode ser aleatorio? digo eu posso definir qual vai ser o formname? ou é algo específico?

Comment: Não, `formname` é o nome do elemento form que está no html da página, ele vai mudar conforme a página que você está capturando os dados, mas você só vai precisar usar ele quando tiver esses casos de mais de um form na página, nos outros você nem precisa passar.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pelo apoio, realmente eu fiquei travado um bom tempo nesta função

Comment: Disponha se a resposta lhe ajudou marque ela como aceita =D